# Default values for attributes contained within value tuples

Tags: c#, valuetuple

Is it possible to define an optional or default attribute within a value tuple?

for example in the below value tuple the `Func<Type> type = null` will be optional:

```
public static void MustMatch(params
    (Func<T, object> prop, Func<dynamic, dynamic> value, Func<Type> type = null)[] mappings)
```

Comment: what does "option" mean? its mean boolean type or other things?

Answer (score 0):

No. But you can create a factory method having a default parameter

```
public static (Func<T, object> prop, Func<dynamic, dynamic> value, Func<Type> type) Param(
    Func<T, object> prop, Func<dynamic, dynamic> value, Func<Type> type = null)
{
    return (prop, value, type);
}
```

Call with (within same class)

```
MustMatch(
    Param(t => 5, d => "hello"),
    (t => 7, d => "world", () => typeof(string))
);
```